# Is it possible to create a table automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode

Im beginner. I use a HTML table code like this *(see below)* for Unicode print using char's Decimal values:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr><td>1</td><td>&#1;</td>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>&#2;</td>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>&#3;</td>
  ...
  <!-- last one: thousandth row -->
  <tr><td>1000</td><td>&#1000;</td>
</table>
```

Is it possible to convert this code into an auto-generated table as follows using JavaScript or JQuery?

```
<table border="1">
  <tr><td>rowNumber</td><td>innerHTML = "\u0026\u0023 + rowNumber + \u003B";</td>
  ...
  <!-- thousandth row -->
  <tr><td>rowNumber</td><td>innerHTML = "\u0026\u0023 + rowNumber + \u003B";</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you must use proper JS code. There is no "inline-js" like "inline-css". You must move it to script tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can start by creating a record-generating function.

```
function generateRecords(recordFn, limit) {
  var records = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    records.push(recordFn.call(null, i, records));
  }
  return records;
}
```

Then you can generate the JSON.

```
generateRecords(i => {
  return {
    dec: i,
    entity: '&amp;&num;' + i + '&semi;',
    rendered: '&#' + i + ';'
  }
}, 1000);
```

Finally, all you need to do is render the JSON to a table.

### Example

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.attrs = function(attrs) {
    var $self = this;
    if (attrs != null) {
      $.each(attrs, function(attr, value) {
        $self.attr(attr, value);
      });
      return $self;
    } else {
      var result = {};
      $.each(this[0].attributes, function(index, attribute) {
        result[attribute.name] = attribute.value;
      });
      return result;
    }
  };
  $.fn.tableFromJson = function(data, attrs, indexField) {
    return this.replaceWith($.tableFromJson.apply(this, arguments));
  };
  $.tableFromJson = function(data, attrs, indexField) {
    var fields = Object.keys(data[0]);
    if (indexField != null) fields.unshift(indexField);
    return $('<table>')
      .append($('<thead>').append($('<tr>').append(fields
        .map(field => $('<th>').text(field)))))
      .append($('<tbody>').append(data
        .map((rec, row) => $('<tr>').append(fields
          .map((field, col) => $('<td>').html(field === indexField ? (row + 1) : rec[field])))))).attrs(attrs);
  };
})(jQuery);

function generateRecords(recordFn, limit) {
  var records = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    records.push(recordFn.call(null, i, records));
  }
  return records;
}

$('.column:nth-child(1) .result').tableFromJson(generateRecords(i => {
  return {
    dec: i,
    entity: '&amp;&num;' + i + '&semi;',
    rendered: '&#' + i + ';'
  }
}, 1000), $('.column:nth-child(1) .result').attrs());

$('.column:nth-child(2) .result').tableFromJson(generateRecords(i => {
  return {
    dec: i,
    rendered: '\u0026\u0023' + i + '\u003B'
  }
}, 1000), $('.column:nth-child(2) .result').attrs());
```

```css
.container { width: 100%; }
.column { display: inline-block; width: 49%; }

table.result {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

table.result,
table.result th,
table.result td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.result th,
table.result td {
  padding: 0.25em;
}

table.result tbody tr td {
  text-align: center;
}

table.result thead tr {
  background: #BBB;
}

table.result tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #EEE;
}

table.result tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <table class="result"></table>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <table class="result"></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try with this

```
var table = $('<table>').prop('border', 1);
for(i=0; i<1000; i++){
    var row = $('<tr><td>' +  i + '</td><td>&#'++'</td></tr>'
    table.append(row);
}

$('#mytable').append(table);
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, Thats possible using javascript/JQuery.For that you need to use proper js code. Below is the sample code that can help you to create table and row,data using jquery.
Below code is responsible to create table tag

```
$('.class-name').append('<table border="3"></table>');
```

This will create table element inside your HTML having classname as .class-name.

Once the table tag is created you can create table row and data element as below.

```
$("table").append(createRow());

function createRow(){
var firstVal = '1st val';
var secondVal = '2nd val';
   var tr = '<tr>' ;
    tr += '<td>' + firstVal  + '</td>';
    tr += '<td>' + secondVal + '</td>';  
    tr +='</tr>';
    return tr;
}
```

This code will generate the table row and will print the table data as st val and 2nd val.
Hope this code may help you